# How to ignore all failure cases for promises with Istanbul

Tags: node.js, promise, q, istanbul

I'm using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for promises in NodeJS along with Istanbul for code coverage. Is there a way to ignore all failure cases. Most of mine are catch-alls in case something unexpected happens I can't replicate in my tests.

For example:

```
somePromise
.then(function() {
  console.log('yay!');
}, function(err) {
  /* istanbul ignore next */ 
  console.error(err);
});
```

Seems a bit laborious to have to add that comment to every failure condition in my code...

Comment: ״ Most of mine are catch-alls in case something unexpected happens I can't replicate in my tests.״ there's your problem right there.

Comment: ...like catch-alls for other methods that I can't control the output from, such as mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that you cannot easily programatically ignore all of your "catchall" promise failures.

The right thing to do here is to use Q inside your tests and a mock library like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to force a promise rejection inside your promise flow, like this :

```
var Q           = require('q');
var sinon       = require("sinon");
var controller  = new Controller(); //Dummy constructor

//controller.method will automatically return a promise with a rejected state
sinon.stub(controller,"method").returns(Q.reject());
```

This way Istanbul **will** enter these parts of your code and you'll have a higher code coverage percentage which is good!

Comment: Ah, yes, in theory that makes sense!. I'm doing integration tests with these specific methods through a running express server, however, and sinon doesn't appear to let me alter the functions inside of it. Thoughts?

Comment: Well if these functions are not exposed and you already test it as a blackbox with all possible inputs it means that your catchall will never trigger even in production. What I'd do here is write functional tests for the controllers directly, bypassing completely the HTTP layer, which is where your error handling should probably be.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Better to break it out and test it then to just ignore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing a bit of everything. To help clean up the error capturing, I created a function that I passed into the promise failure catch so that istanbul just sees it as a variable rather than a function that wasn't entered. I can then unit test the error handling separately.

```
var errCatch = function(err) { /* something */ };

somePromise
.then(function() {
  console.log('yay!');
}, errCatch);
```